# Card View (Appcompat) causes app to crash

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-framelayout, android-cardview

I am trying to use the Android Quiz sample but and I want to put all of the contents into a card view. I used the example of a card view (Which works completely) from the Android Navigation Drawer Sample. When running my app, it crashes. Yet no bugs are shown in the code. What is causing this? Here is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.support.wearable.quiz.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/read_quiz_from_file_button"
            android:text="@string/read_from_file_button"
            android:onClick="readQuizFromFile"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/edit_question"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/question_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/choices_radio_group">
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/edit_choice_a"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_a_radio"
                    android:checked="true" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/edit_choice_b"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_b_radio"
                    android:checked="false" />
                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:text="@string/edit_choice_c"
                        android:id="@+id/choice_c_radio" />
                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:text="@string/edit_choice_d"
                        android:id="@+id/choice_d_radio" />
            </RadioGroup>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_a_text" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_b_text" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_c_text" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/choice_d_text" />
              </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/add_question"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_question"
            android:onClick="addQuestion"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/quiz_status"
            android:id="@+id/quiz_status"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/questions_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
         </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quiz_buttons"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible">
            <Button android:id="@+id/reset_quiz_button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/reset_quiz"
                android:onClick="resetQuiz">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/new_quiz_button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_quiz"
                android:onClick="newQuiz">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

For reference, here is the code of the Navigation Drawer Sample's card view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- The CardView needs to be wrapped to ensure spacing is applied correctly. -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        style="@style/Widget.SampleDashboard.Card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.SampleDashboard.Item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text1"
                style="@style/Widget.SampleDashboard.Item.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text2"
                style="@style/Widget.SampleDashboard.Item.Description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the code that was posted on the blog for this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Your card content -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to android development.

Comment: Are you referring to the error messages that are showing in the logcat? (I am just asking before I post it. Don't want to post the wrong thing)

Comment: Yes, that will inform you what is causing the crash.

Comment: http://justpaste.it/j1cx

Comment: See the cause `ClassNotFoundException`? Have you got `com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2` (or whatever the current version is) added to your gradle dependencies? It's packaged separate from appcompat.

Comment: I just looked and I don't have it on there. Strange as I put it in there before even attempting to add in the card view. Must have been deleted during the sync process. I am building it now and I will tell you if that works. Thank you :)

Comment: This, in addition to the answer below fixed the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an answer if you'd like to accept it. The issue was a `ClassNotFoundException` because the gradle dependency for `CardView` was not added.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably already using the updated version of android (AndroidX or ‘Jetpack’) and the seemingly latest versions of RecyclerView and CardView is ‘not new enough’.

replace card view dependency by this one :
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

and use this code snippet in the XML file for the card view :
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView instead of android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the android namespace reference multiple times. Namespace references should be made on the first element only. Same goes for the tools namespace reference.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

I assume this is the error you are having but it is difficult to tell as you do not state what the error is.

EDIT

Like this...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.support.wearable.quiz.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
```

Comment: I just posted the errors that I was given. But I will try that and let you know if that works. Thanks :)

Comment: So do both the tools and android namespaces need to show up only once, or do I need to delete the duplicate android namespace and the tool namespace all together?

Comment: 2nd one. No duplicates, all on first element.

Comment: Your solution and darnmason's solutions worked. Thank you both :)